# How to add a path permanatly in matlab and save it?

Tags: matlab

How to add a path permanantly in matlab and save it?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776258/where-is-matlab-setpath-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is The Mathworks' documentation on setting the search path in MATLAB; note the section at the bottom titled "How MATLAB Stores the Search Path" about making changes permanent: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html

Comment: link dumping is not the correct way ;) to gain rep it is adviced to copy the important parts over and link to the source.

Comment: i see y'all are a full service shop over here (i don't intend to improve this answer; someone else is welcome to post something more polished)

Comment: fine. a moderator probably will delete it then ;)

Comment: @ Tim Smith: I added the path location in pathdef.m file located in "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/toolbox/local". "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a" is my matlabroot location. I had to change the permissions of the 'local' folder before editing pathdef.m. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Changes to your path will be continued if you add the path to your startup.m file.  You can change it in Matlab by entering into the Matlab command window:

```
edit startup
```

Then add the path to file the same way you would in the command line

```
addpath('/path/to/dir');
```

You can also use startup.m to permanently change figure defaults and most other settings.